# One data is not recovered after submit form

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a search form. In this form I have two select boxes, one for the countries and the second for the cities named "destination". The second one depends on the selected country. Also I have some others inputs too.

After selecting a country, all cities related to it are displayed correctly using ajax query.

The problem is if I choose a country and submit the form, the destination is not recovered in address bar, but if I do not select a country, the destination will be recovered.

This is how the address bar appears if I don not select a country

```
/q?title=&country=&destination=&airport=&departureDate=&returnDate=&price=
```

and this is how the address bar appears if I select a country. As you can see the destination is missing

```
/q?title=&country=1&airport=&departureDate=&returnDate=&price=
```

**NOTE** I'm using a similar form with method POST to create or edit new travel and it works fine

**SearchTravelType**

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

//........
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\Country;

class SearchTravelType extends AbstractType
{
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {

  ->add('country', 'entity', array(
     'required' => true,
     'class' => 'AppBundle:Country',
     'property' => 'en',
     'multiple' => false,
     'expanded' => false,
     'label' => 'ِCountry',
     'empty_value' => '' ))
  //....

  $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Country $country = null) {
        $cities = null === $country ? array() : $country->getCities();

        $form->add('destination', 'entity', array(
            'class'       => 'AppBundle:CityWorld',
            'choices'     => $cities,
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'property'    => 'name',
            'label' => 'Destination'));
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // this would be your entity
            $data = $event->getData();

            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getCountry());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('country')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
            // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
            $country = $event->getForm()->getData();

            // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
            // the parent to the callback functions!
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $country);
        }
    );


}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Travel'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return null;
}
}
```

This is the form and javascript code

```
<form method="get" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form" >

 {{ form_widget(form.country, { 'id': 'country' }) }}

 {{ form_widget(form.destination, { 'id': 'city' }) }}

//.............
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $county = $('#country');

$county.change(function () {
    // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');

    var data = {};
    data[$county.attr('name')] = $county.val();
    // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ path('dashboard_travel_search', {'agence_slug': agence.slug}) }}',
            type: 'POST',           data: data,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#city').replaceWith(
                    // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                    $(html).find('#city')
            );
        }
    });
});
```

This is the controller

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("agence", options={"mapping": {"agence_slug":"slug"}})
 */
public function searchAction(Request $request, Agence $agence)
{
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('view', $agence)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Unauthorised access!');
    }
    /* Instantiate Travel to not get this error
    Error: Call to a member function getCountry() on a non-object
    */
    $travel = new Travel();

    $form = $this->createForm(new SearchTravelType(), $travel);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST' ) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    $title = $request->query->get('title');
    $country = $request->query->get('country');
    $destination = $request->query->get('destination');
    $price = $request->query->get('price');
    $departureDate = $request->query->get('departureDate');
    $returnDate = $request->query->get('returnDate');
    $nbDays = $request->query->get('nbDays');
    $nbNights = $request->query->get('nbNights');
    $airport = $request->query->get('airport');
    $enabled = $request->query->get('enabled');

    $qb = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Travel')->getListSearchTravelsDashboard($agence, $title, $country, $destination, $price, $departureDate, $returnDate, $nbDays, $nbNights, $airport, $enabled);

    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $qb,
        $request->query->get('page', 1), 10);
    $pagination->setSortableTemplate('KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link_dashboard.html.twig');

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Dashboard/Travel:list-search.html.twig', array(
        'pagination' => $pagination,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'agence' => $agence,
    ));

}
```

This is the Twig HTML markup of the generated form:

```
<table id="sample-table-1" class="table table-responsives table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="get" action="">
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.title) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.country, { 'id': 'country' }) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.destination, { 'id': 'city' }) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.airport) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.departureDate) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.returnDate) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.price) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.nbDays) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.nbNights) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.enabled) }} {{ form_rest(form) }}</td>
            <td><span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm" title="Rechercher">
                <i class="icon-search bigger-110"></i></button>
            </span>
        </form>
    </tr>
```

I have put it outside the table and it works fine now. Is there any explanation?

Comment: Are you using AJAX to show related cities? If so please provide the JavaScript for showing the related cities. Also check if you can receive the selected option with JavaScript after choosing the city. If you can not receive the checked select option via JavaScript, check what the script will change after selecting a city in the DOM. It can be, that it will only change a class or attribute to show the selection, but internal it will not check the option (e.g. with a `checked` attribute).

Comment: @julmot  , I'm using Ajax JavaScript to update the destination form field according to the current selection in the country field and I use EVENTS to select cities. Here is the example in the documentation.  (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because the form is **into a table** like this

```
 <table id="sample-table-1" class="table table-responsives table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
            <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="get" action="">
                <td class="center">-</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.title) }}</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.country, { 'id': 'country' }) }}</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.destination, { 'id': 'city' }) }}</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.airport) }}</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.departureDate) }}</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.returnDate) }}</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.price) }}</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.nbDays) }}</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.nbNights) }}</td>
                <td>{{ form_widget(form.enabled) }} {{ form_rest(form) }}</td>
                <td><span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm" title="Rechercher">
                    <i class="icon-search bigger-110"></i></button>
                </span>
            </form>
        </tr>
```

I have put it **outside the table** and it works fine now. is there any explication ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you cannot have a `form` HTML element inside a `tr` HTML element. A `tr` element can only have `td` and `th` elements inside, according to W3C specification - see [permitted contents of the `tr` element in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html#tr-content-model).

It is a problem similar to the one mentioned here in the W3C standards section - the markup is broken. See [unexpected table markup informations in the W3C HTML standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#unexpected-markup-in-tables).

Moreover, not only you have a `form` element directly inside a `tr` element, but you also don't close the last `td` tag after your submit button, which, I suppose, has something to do with the issue as well.

Your markup is the source of all problems there, I don't know if any browser might handle such code correctly. Have everything validate through a W3C validator and then you can search for issues in controllers et al. Invalid HTML code can be the source of many unexpected problems, which are then hard to debug and you will often end up searching in the wrong place. And I'm talking from experience here.

Comment: @hous I've added your Twig sample code from your answer to the original question, I think it shall be present also there for easier reference (the edit might not be yet visible due to an undergoing StackOverflow peer-review process).

Comment: but why all aothers inputs are recovred unless "destination" ? don't you think it has a relation with the javascript code ? 

`success: function (html) {
            $('#city').replaceWith(
               
                    $(html).find('#city')
            );`

Comment: @hous it might be the case, but only because the HTML is not valid. Probably the #city field is not being found then (in a response), so it might be replaced with an empty value. A valid HTML code is what's most important here to start looking for other issues - then you might start debugging your JS code. You wrote yourself that when you corrected the HTML structure, everything started working as expected - so maybe the two things are in fact connected, but it all comes down to the HTML being invalid in the first place, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, better use a separate controller action just to retrieve the cities you need and replace only the options in select field. Rendering whole form with pagination etc. is a bit overkill.
Secondly, check what exactly did you get as the html from your ajax call, especially whether the input selected by $(html).find('#city') contains the 'name' attribute. Missing value from submitted form has nothing in common with the Symfony2 Framework itself, it's all about correct HTML content.